# How to install gcc 2.95.3 on ubuntu 14.04 64 bit?

Tags: gcc

How to install gcc 2.95.3 on ubuntu 14.04 64 bit.
I require to do this to compile kernel 2.6.10. Newer versions of gcc do not compile the linux kernel 2.6.10.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Any specific reason for using older version of gcc?

Comment: He. Getting 4.7 to compile is annoying enough, good luck with 2.95.

Comment: Hi Snoop, To compile kernel 2.6.10. Newer versions of gcc do not compile the linux kernel 2.6.10.

Comment: source is here, http://gcc.cybermirror.org/releases/gcc-2.95.3/  ubuntu has 2.95.4 packages but unlikely you'll be able to install, certainly not if on amd64, - http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/g/gcc-2.95/

Comment: http://www.trevorpounds.com/blog/?p=111 provides a very good tutorial on installing older gcc compilers on Debian/Ubuntu X86_64 machines. Unfortunately, make step fails reporting error about glibc library.

Comment: Sorry doug, that did not work for me.